# Configure unique domains for several tomcat webapps

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I follow the instructions from [here](https://www.jvmhost.com/articles/how-to-configure-tomcat-with-multiple-virtual-hosts/) and this to my `server.xml` file for each domain/webapp:

```
<Host name="domain1.com" autoDeploy="true" appBase="webapps_domain1" unpackWARs="true">
     <Alias>www.domain1.com</Alias>
     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"   
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" 
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/>
</Host>
```

and restart the tomcat, but I cannot access the webapp using the domain after that. I also create the directory `webapp_domain1` in `/var/lib/tomcat9` and copy a war file to it with the name `ROOT.war` (also for each domain/webapp).

Anyone can tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: In `<Host` add different `docBase` to the specific app

Comment: can you give an example for that?

Comment: I add to the tag `Host`: `<Context path="" docBase="ROOT" debug="0" reloadable="true"/> `, and still got the same problem.

Comment: No, docBase should point to the directory where the different app is deployed. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54366546/2908599

Comment: After follow the instructions in the answer, I have this in my `server.xml` file: https://pastebin.com/GGjSQqCH. And I have created a `ROOT.xml` file in the directory `conf/<domain>` for each domain with this content: `Context docBase="/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps_loja/ROOT.war" path=""></Context>`. But the problem continues.

Comment: nevermind, I just solve the problem now. I had to change the port for tomcat from 8080 to 80 (I figure out this when I notice I could access the webapp with http://domain1:8080 instead of only http://domain1)